# Why some jsff page can ignore all mds customizations applied to it in oracle adf?

Tags: jsp, jsf, customization, facelets, oracle-adf

I am trying to customize a .jsff page fragment of one of oracle adf/webcenter taskflows, but it seems that no customization rules are getting aplied to it, while other jsff's in the same package are customizing just fine. What could be the possible reason this particular jsff is not customizable? How to diagnose such problem?

In my particular case, i am trying to alter the `oracle.webcenter.framework_11.1.1/peopleconnections-connections-view.jar!/oracle/webcenter/peopleconnections/connections/view/jsf/fragments/TableOfPeople.jsff` page fragment with the following customization rules:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<mds:customization version="11.1.1.64.93"
                   xmlns:mds="http://xmlns.oracle.com/mds">
  <mds:replace node="icbp1"/>
  <mds:modify element="icbcf1">
    <mds:attribute name="width" value="200"/>
  </mds:modify>
</mds:customization>
```

but this customization have no visible effect on resulting page render, while other jsffs in the same `/oracle/webcenter/peopleconnections/connections/view/jsf/fragments/` package, for instance `TableOfConnections-ListView.jsff` is altering just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly there should be a `Customization allowed` flag set to `true` (look at the image below):

[image]

Then, in the *Web Content* folder you will have a customization file for the selected page. It should be stored in `mdssys/mdx/pageName.jspx.rdf` and there you should apply the customization rules for the component in the given page.